# startActivityForResult is not working properly

Tags: java, android

I have two activities activity Home.java and ApplicationSettings.java

Now both are extending another activity BaseActivity.java which is in a library project and this BaseActivity.java makes a call to DeviveListActivity.java by calling startActivityForResult();
and after getting the device address its comes back to onActivityResult() of BaseActivity.java

What BaseActivity.java does is, it connects to a Bluetooth device,
and i can create a connection to that Bluetooth device from Home.java activity as well as from ApplicationSettings.java activity

now if i make a connection from Home.java and then goto ApplicationSettings.java activity, the connection works fine as connection was made from Home.java so no issues in this case

but when i haven't made any connection from Home.java and i click on Application Settings, ApplicationSettings.java activity is started and when i try to make a connection from this activity ApplicationSettings.java, there is a problem

i collected some logs for activity lifecycle which are as below

these are when i make a connection from the Home.java Activity(which works fine)

```
Home.java: OnCreate 
BaseActivity.java: OnCreate 
Home.java: OnStart 
BaseActivity.java: OnStart 
Home.java: OnResume 
BaseActivity.java: started activity for result (DeviveListActivity.java)
Home.java(15360): OnPause 
DeviceListActivity.java: OnCreate 
DeviceListActivity.java: OnResume 
DeviceListActivity.java: Result set for device address and called finish() 
DeviceListActivity.java: OnPause 
BaseActivity.java: In onActivityResult 
Home.java: OnResume 
DeviceListActivity.java: OnDestroy
```

I noticed in the logs above that when BaseActivity.java is in OnStart while the startactivityforresult(DeviveListActivity.java) is called and it never goes in OnStop till the onActivityResult is called

but in the logs below where i try to make a connection from ApplicationSettings.java activity then the logs are

```
Home.java: OnCreate
BaseActivity.java: OnCreate
Home.java: OnStart
BaseActivity.java: OnStart
Home.java: OnResume
Home.java: OnPause
ApplicationSettings.java: OnCreate
ApplicationSettings.java: OnStart
ApplicationSettings.java: OnResume
Home.java: OnStop
BaseActivity.java: onStop
BaseActivity.java: started activity for result (DeviveListActivity.java) 
ApplicationSettings.java: OnPause
DeviceListActivity.java: OnCreate
DeviceListActivity.java: OnResume
DeviceListActivity.java: Result set for device address and called finish()
DeviceListActivity.java: OnPause
ApplicationSettings.java: OnResume  //here it comes(which is wrong)
```

Here  noticed in the logs above that when ApplicationSettings.java is created and started, BaseActivity.java is in OnStop and then the startactivityforresult(DeviveListActivity.java) is called and BaseActivity is not started again 
and then result is set but then it should have gone to BaseActivity.java: In onActivityResult
instead ApplicationSettings.java: OnResume was called

which i don't want to happen because the whole flow changes when it enters in OnResume of ApplicationSettings.java

Any suggestions how can i send it to onActivityResult of BaseActivity.java ?

Comment: Was your onActivityResult got called ?

Comment: it gets called when i go back to Home.java activity

Comment: You cant stop the call to the onResume, instead what you can do is do all the other operations of the activity in onCreate and set a flag to handle it.

Comment: it won't help because anyhow the BaseActivity.java will go in OnStop as soon as Home.java goes in OnStop because it extends BaseActivity.java and BaseActivity's startactivityforresult won't get called unless i click on connectbutton which is in Activity ApplicationSetting.java

Comment: Where is your `startActivityForResult()`  and how it gets executed?

Comment: @NigamPatro startActivityForResult()  is in BaseActivity.java and it gets executed when a call is made to a method in BaseActivity.java from Home